# How do I make autoshrink within a UITableView cell text without hiding details label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I make a UITableView and every time the text label is big enough to get over detail text label, the details dont shows up.

I has seted a CGRec smaller but has no success.

Ps.: Im using Xcode 4, iOS5.

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to display a Bing Text label in UITableView..  And the cell should be expanded to its length..  am I correct..

Comment: Actually, the cell label expands more than have to. I have solved the problem by instancing a new label and adding to a custom UITableViewCell, overriding the original details label.
Thanks for help.

Comment: You are welcome..  if you find the answer.. please post your answer to your own question so that it may help some one in future thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Use below code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, your text in textLabel inside cell will shrink as you want.

```
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
```